# Fantasy series where 5 or 6 teens go through a portal to a world with dragons

Tags: story-identification

Searching for an older series that I read a few books to. All I can remember is that it was about 5 or 6 teens that traveled (or fell) through a portal to a different world, one with dragons. I remember they were able to travel back and forth to their world. I believe that one of the character's names was "Zerena" if I'm not mistaken.  In one of the books they fell into a chamber of gold (riches) and encountered one of the dragons. Pretty sure the word "World" was in the title, but through all my searching I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy!  What language was it in? Can you describe any additional plot points? Please try to provide some more detail. **You might also want to use a more descriptive question title.**